# JS Not resubmitted form if refresh page

Tags: javascript, forms, form-submit, page-refresh

I have a file in js structured like this:

```
if ( window.history.replaceState ) {
   window.history.replaceState( null, null, window.location.href );
}
```

the function blocks the submit request if it has already been executed if you want to reload the page.  on desktop devices it works while from my smartphone no.  have any idea why?

Thanks